# How to report bootstrap simulation?

Tags: bootstrap, descriptive-statistics, reporting

I am conducting a simulation study, I simulate $N=10000$ samples of size $n=50$ from a distribution $F(;\theta)$, then I obtain a bootstrap sample of size $B=1000$ from the MLE of $\theta$. Some bootstrap samples of the MLE of $\theta$ contain extreme observations, so I want to avoid summary statistics involving moments. I want to report the coverage of some bootstrap intervals as well as some other statistics. What do people typically report in this kind of studies?

Comment: If you produce bootstrap replicas of the MLE, $\hat{\theta}_1,\ldots,\hat{\theta}_B$, a confidence interval based on the quantiles of this bootstrap sample should avoid the most extreme values.